# 2 lans on the same switch safe?

Tags: networking, firewall, switch, local-area-network

I have a modem with 5 ports. Each port gets a static IP address from the web. Basically if i ping one of those static IP addresses from home i am pinging directly one of those ports.

On the first port there is our company router/firewall followed by a switch and all the company accesses the internet through the same public IP.

What would happen if id connect the second port of the modem directly to the switch?

My expectations are that nothing happens since it has a different subnet, and it would be possible from single workstations to bypass the server by simply changing the lan adapter settings.

Am I right on this? Is it safe or would it cause security holes?

What i would need to archive is that some computers should be able to bypass the firewall on some situations.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diagram is a big help in clarifying this question.

What you're doing is OK **if and only if** your big switch is manageable, and you can configure VLANs to forcibly separate the outside-the-router-firewall traffic from the inside-the-router-firewall traffic.

When an internal machine needs to temporarily move to the external LAN, you can change its adaptor settings **and** tell the switch to take its port out the internal VLAN and add it to the external one.

Otherwise it's just a matter of time before someone inside notices that they can give themselves an interface alias on the external network and completely sidestep the firewall, or someone who has compromised one of the external boxes notices that if they give themselves an alias on the internal network, they have bypassed your firewall and your corporate LAN is at their disposal.

If you are doing this to deliberately bypass this separation, you're taking a **huge** risk.

**Edit**: what on earth makes you think that a computer can only be on one of the two LANs at any one time, if the switch isn't enforcing that separation?  Suppose that I am an attacker, and I have suborned one of the machines currently attached to the modem (which is itself a switch).  We'll call that machine ALF.

I now give ALF an interface alias with an appropriate address for the internal network (whose existence and addressing I can easily deduce by watching ARP broadcasts on ALF's NIC in promiscuous mode).  Now I can directly PING - and therefore attack - server, without the firewall ever seeing my traffic.

I'll say this one more time, so it's really clear: **if you bypass your firewall with a cable to your main switch, and don't make any arrangements for the traffic down that cable to be kept away from your main network, you're dead**.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! we are not worried about our internal employees. but we are worried about the server beeing acessed without firewall.  I do not know if it is managed or not, lets assume it is not managed. How can someone access the main lan though this secondary lan from outside, if every pc is only in one of the two lans at any given time?

Comment: Which machine is "*the server*"?  It doesn't appear on your diagram.

Comment: its just one of the computers on the main lan.. we want the files on that shared directories to be safe from outside.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get IP addresses from the Web.

If you connect two DHCP servers to the same switch, things can start behaving in unexpected ways. There are a few ways you can get around this, but they are error prone, so why not use the more secure approach and connect that one computer directly to the desired switch port without going through the switch?

There are other solutions, but they require either a managed switch or some control over the DHCP replies send by the ISP:

- Filter DHCP packets on the switch
- Configure the DHCP servers to only respond to certain MAC adresses
- Disable the DHCP server handing replies to the modem, and use static IP addresses on the computer you want to communicate directly through the modem.
- Use VLANs